# regular expressions - my expression

Tags: regex

I've got `(To) [a-z]+` as regular expression and I've got sentence: `To kot dziki pies.`

And If I compile it I will retrieve `To kot`.

So what can I do to retrieve only word after (only kot) "To" instead of "To kot"?

Comment: could you give me sample in php?

Answer (score 4):

`^To (\w+)$` should do the trick. `\w` is shorthand for *any word character*, eg. *a-z* in English; other characters in other languages. If you put parens around *To* as in your example, it will create a *matched group*, which means the match for [a-z]+ will be in the second group, and *To* will be in the first group.

I can really recommend using an interactive tool for testing and developing regular expression, such as [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).

Answer (score 2):

use groups inside the regular expression - 
"To ([a-z]+)" and then retrieve group 1's value, it will contain "kot" supplied your example string.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use lookbehinds:

`(?<=To )[a-z]+`

Then the To does not become part of the captured expression.

Comment: OP didn't have it when I answered the question :p